# Regex: Find those html tags which contains at least 3 of some keywords

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this words, of which at least three of them are found in any sentence in English.

`was, where, were, some, then, than, that, can, by, the, and, with, over, there, is, as, also, through, from, while, just, like, for, such, if, else, still, again, want, will, wish, make, made, well, have, had, has, it, be, do, say, others, go, know, see, think, look, give, use, find, tell, ask, work, seem, feel, try, leave, call, get, take, too, in, addition, to, could, who, he, she, because, of, your, yours, their, doesn't, are, an, these, this, those, but, at, whom, or, out, how, when, between, his, her, they, them, my, without, maybe, even, show, can't, must, couldn't, now, i'm, many, come, own, self, seen, it’s, we, any, other, coming, so, found, more, much, all, very, same, did, which, does, on`

Also, I have these two html tags, but only the content of the first one is in English:

`<meta name="description" content="Simply Red are a British soul and pop band which formed in Manchester in 1985. The lead vocalist of the band is singer and songwriter Mick Hucknall by">`

and one tag in russian:

`<meta name="description" content="Simply Red - британская соул- и поп-группа, образованная в Манчестере в 1985 году. Ведущим вокалистом группы является певец и автор песен Мик Хакнелл.">`

So, I want to check all html files that contain tags whose content is written in English. For this, I must find those html tags which contains at least 3 of that keywords from the beginning.

My regex, with just few words (short version), looks like this:

SEARCH: **`(?-s)<meta name="description".+?(?:(was|is|as|on|and|in)).+>`**

and the larger version will be:

**`(?-s)<meta name="description".*?(was|where|were|some|then|than|that|can|by|the|and|with|over|there|is|as|also|through|from|while|just|like|for|such|if|else|still|again|want|will|wish|make|made|well|have|had|has|it|be|do|say|others|go|know|see|think|look|give|use|find|tell|ask|work|seem|feel|try|leave|call|get|take|too|in|addition|to|could|who|he|she|because|of|your|yours|their|doesn't|are|an|these|this|those|but|at|whom|or|out|how|when|between|his|her|they|them|my|without|maybe|even|show|can't|must|couldn't|now|i'm|many|come|own|self|seen|it’s|we|any|other|coming|so|found|more|much|all|very|same|did|which|does|on).+>`**

Ok, the problem is that my regex find also the second tag, whose content is written in russian. I must find only the first one (in english)

Comment: May be I'm wrong but I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1686). Why don't you check if the content description doesn't contain russian letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is too big, so to demonstrate the technique,
here is an example on a small list of four words,
`one two three four`.

[image]

Here is an explanation of the search string: `(one|two|three|four).*(?-1).*(?-1)`

- `(one|two|three|four)` : Capture one of the words in the group
- `.*` : Find any number of characters
- `(?-1)` : Find another match of the group one behind this one (recursive subpattern)

Comment: super answer, thanks. So, in my case, the short version, will be FIND: **`<meta name="description" content=".*(are|the|in|you).*(?-1).*(?-1).+>`**

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: The regex  above doesn't work on Python, so in order to work it can be change a little bit, as this one: **`<p class="text_obisnuit">.*((are|the|in|you).*){3,}.*</p>`**